# Javascript data structure for json

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to work with a pretty simple data structure but just cant get it right.

I have an array which looks like that :

```
[{"object":"name","context":"..."},{"object":"name","context":"..."}]
```

Assume this structure is kept in a variable names object_list

All I want is to add an additional field in the base structure so my object will looks like :

```
[{"object":"name","context":"..."},{"object":"name","context":"..."}],
additional_data : "data"
```

in context of code I would like to be able to :

```
var item = object_list[0];
var additional_data = object_list.additional_data;
```

cant find a way to add to my array that extra field.

Comment: You can have an object inside an array or an array in an object, but an object can't be an array and vice-versa. I think you're mixing it up a little too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var object_list = [{"object":"name","context":"..."}];
object_list.additional_data = "data";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3yDb/

Comment: Seems to work. it doesn't work on my case for some reason, but it does "solve" what I tried to get.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you currently have the array:

```
var object_list = [{"object":"name","context":"..."},{"object":"name","context":"..."}];
```

You need a new object, with that as a property, and another property:

```
var newObj = {
    object_list: object_list,
    additional_data: "data"
}
```

Then you can do:

```
newObj.object_list; //array
newObj.additional_data; //your data
```

Important side note, since JS objects are just references, changing anything in `object_list` will also be reflected in `newObj.object_list`

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid.. in your suggestion to reach the additional data I need to do newObj.additional_data and to reach the array i need newObj.object_list. I want to be able to reach the additional_data through object_list.additional_data.

Comment: @Nuno_147 -- You can't. That's not a valid JS object `[], key: val`. The proper is `{ key: [], key: val }`

Comment: so to correct it I basically need to name my list in the structure, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do followings with JS arrays. They are all valid but strange.

> var object_list = [{"object":"name","context":"..."},{"object":"name","context":"..."}];
>
> object_list.field1 = 'some value';
>
> object_list['field2'] = 'some other value';

Then you can use object_list as usual array and also as an object. Below are the same.

> object_list.field1
>
> object_list['field1']

It is like a map with different types of keys, in your case integer and string.